# Annotation that returns a warning if a method is not called

Tags: java, annotations

I have the following class:

```
public class PortraitWidget {

    public PortraitWidget() {

    }

    // @mustBeCalled?
    public void dispose() {

    }
}
```

When I create a new instance of PortraitWidget without calling dispose, I would like the compiler/Intellij to warn me:

```
new PortraintWidget();
```

Is there a Java annotation that will return a warning to the compiler if a method in a class is not called?

Comment: Just call it yourself (in the constructor etc...)? If you mean you want to be warned if it is not called *ever* then it's a whole other problem and the answer is no.

Comment: yeah thats what I wanted to know

Comment: Decent IDEs will warn you if a `private` method is not used, but for non-`private` methods, that’s not possible as nobody can claim to know the entire code.